# complexification and maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

let B be  a commutative unital real algebra and C its complexification
viewed as the cartesian product of B with itself.
If M is a maximal ideal in A, is the cartesian product of M with itself
a maximal ideal in C?

Comment: Note that viewing $C$ as $B\times B$ may be correct as vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, but it is an incredibly bad way to work with the complexification, since you will lose the algebra structure on $C$. For instance, if $B=\mathbb{R}$, then $C=\mathbb{C}$ is certainly not isomorphic to $B\times B$ as a ring.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  Try taking $B=\mathbb{C}$ and $M=0$.

Answer (score 0):

indeed,  (z,iz) (z,-iz)=(0,0); so (z,iz) belongs to a max ideal which strictly contains the ideal $\{(0,0)\}$. What is then the relation between the
max ideals in B and its complexification C?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE!! http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Try using Mathjax for writing from next time!!